# Oxygen IDE not launching

Tags: java, eclipse

My java version is  "10.0.2",  I've installed eclipse oxygen.  When I launch I was prompted a error and informed to check the logs.  Below is the output.

```
!SESSION 2018-08-04 15:42:58.284 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0-vfinal-2017-09-29T14:34:02Z-Typesafe
java.version=10.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-08-04 15:43:03.612
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 24 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-08-04 15:43:03.623
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
```

What should I do to overcome this ?  Is this anything to do with java version.

Thank you.

Comment: Oxygen 4.7.0 won't run on Java 9 / 10 without modifying the eclipse.ini. If you want to use Java 10 use the current Eclipse Photon release (4.8)

Comment: Thank @greg-449, would be greatful if you share the parameters to be modified in the ini file

Comment: The duplicate contains that information

Comment: thank @greg-449 will check it